# Follow-on to refreshing charts in c#

Tags: c#, charts

Over the past couple of days, I have been struggling with how to refresh my charts in c#. The chart is updated with data from the database through databinding. Unfortunately, when I save new data to the database, the chart does not automatically, I always have to exit the application and log in again in order to for the chart to be updated.

In order to solve this problem, I decided to abandon databinding and programmatically create my chart which loads whenever the application launches.I then created a button called 'Refresh', which I use to refresh my chart. This has introduced a new issue. Whenever I click the 'Refresh' button, the system retains the old chart and adds the updated chart to it 'side-by-side'. If I click a second time, it displays 3 copies of the chart 'side-by-side'. This continues ad infinitum.

Below are my codes and I am attaching screenshots for your perusal.

```
 //this is my constructor
      public ChartDemo()
      {
          InitializeComponent();

        connectionString = "Data Source=ADMINISTRATOR;Initial Catalog=AMIS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=1234";
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            cnn.Open();

            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
                       }

        //this loads the chart whenever the application is launched
        loadChart();
    }

  private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //this is used to refersh my chart
        loadChart();

    }

    public void loadChart() {


        // this populates my chart with data from the database
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_salary;", cnn);
        SqlDataReader dr;


        try
        {

            cnn.Open();
            dr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();


            while (dr.Read())
            {
                this.chart1.Series["salaryChart"].Points.AddXY(dr.GetString(1), dr.GetInt32(2));

            }
            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

Attached are screenshots [chartsScreenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTqB3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update code add this line  this.chart1.Series["salaryChart"].Points.Clear();
here is your updated code

```
 public void loadChart() {


    // this populates my chart with data from the database
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_salary;", cnn);
    SqlDataReader dr;


    try
    {

        cnn.Open();
        dr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();

this.chart1.Series["salaryChart"].Points.Clear();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            this.chart1.Series["salaryChart"].Points.AddXY(dr.GetString(1), dr.GetInt32(2));

        }
        cnn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in load chart

`this.Refresh();`